# solution to optimization problem

Tags: optimization

> For the problem: $\min {x_1}^2$ subject to $x_1 \leq -1$ and ${x_1}^2 + {x_2}^2 \leq 2$

The possible solutions are: $(x_1,x_2)= (-1,0)$ and $(x_1,x_2)= (-1,-1)$. The optimal value is $1$. Are these solutions correct? If yes, can I include both of them as optimal solution? I am new to optimization. Pls bear with me.

Comment: Your objective function does not depend on $x_2$, haven't you forgotten something?

Answer (score 0):

There are obviously more solutions: $x_1 = -1$ and $-1 \le x_2 \le 1$.

Comment: So this problem has many  optimal solutions but one optimal value ?

Comment: Precisely, yes.